# sig literals in Alloy

Tags: alloy

How can I write out a literal for a sig in Alloy? Consider the example below.

```
sig Foo { a: Int }
fact { #Foo = 1 }
```

If I execute this, I get

```
| this/Foo | a |
|----------|---|
| Foo⁰     | 7 |
```

In the evaluator, I know I can get a reference to the `Foo` instance with `Foo$0` but how can I write a literal that represents the same value?

I've tried `{a: 7}`, but this is not equal to `Foo$0`. This is intentionally a trivial example, but I'm debugging a more complex model and I need to be able to write out literals of sigs with multiple fields.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, this is one of the well hidden secrets! :-) Clearly in your model you cannot refer to *atoms* since the model is defining all possible values of those atoms. However, quite often you need your *hands* on *some* atom to reason about it. That is, you want to be able to *name* some objects.

The best way to get 'constants' is to create a predicate you call from a `run` clause. In this predicate, you define names for atoms you want to discuss. You only have to make sure this predicate is `true`.

```
pred collision[ car1, car2 : Car, road : Road ] {
   // here you can reason about car1 and car2
}
run collision for 10
```

Another way is to create a quantification whenever you need to have some named objects:

```
run  {
   some car1, car2 : Car, road : Road {
      // here you can reason about car1 and car2 and road
   }
} for 10
```

There was a [recent discussion](https://github.com/AlloyTools/org.alloytools.alloy/pull/76#issue-231731649) to add these kinds of instances to the language so that [Kodkod](https://github.com/emina/kodkod) could take advantage of them. (It would allow faster solving and it is extremely useful for test cases of your model.) However, during a discussion this solution I presented came forward and it does not require any new syntax.

Comment: In the evaluator, I already can refer to constants which have been created. But my problem is that I want to construct constants which are not directly defined by the model. In my example above, suppose I wanted to construct a `Foo` instance with an `a` value of 6. Is there no way to do this without modifying the model? If I need to change the model every time, it would make debugging rather challenging.

Comment: You make specific debugging predicates to do that. You can include your model in a _debug_ model so these test/debug predicates do not pollute your model. However, imho they are probably the most interesting parts of your model for newcomers.

Comment: I don't see how that would solve my problem. Suppose in my example that I want a `Foo` instance where `a` is 6. How would I write a debugging predicate to get such an instance so I could pass it to a function?

Comment: Which is fine if I know that I want `a=6` beforehand, but doesn't really help interactively.

Answer (score 0):

try to put a limitation for 'Integer' in the 'run' command. I mean :

```
sig Foo {a : Int}
fact{ #Foo = 1}

pred show {}
run show for 1 Foo, 2 Int
```

[image: The Instances with value for Foo = 1]